# Chain Request From Room with Kotlin Coroutine and Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I want to request two times for different Flow types then add result in single live data for observation.
but only get the first result.

> ParentModel is the parent of Note and FolderWithNote data classes.

```
  val allItems: MutableLiveData<List<ParentModel>> = MutableLiveData()

  fun getAllItems() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        noteRepository.getFoldersWithNotes()
            .collect {
                allItems.postValue(it)
            }

        noteRepository.getAllNotes()
            .map {
                databaseNoteMapper.mapFromEntityList(it)
            }
            .collect {
                allItems.postValue(it)
            }
    }
}
```

and i observe like this in fragment

```
    viewModel.allItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        adapter.setItems(it)
    })
```

I want to show all Notes and Folderwithnotes in my recyclerView that I handle different bind of them in my Recycler adapter.

Answer (score 1):

This is for sure, because the first Flow collect will block waiting for the data returned by the database. You need to open two sub-coroutines to complete the collect of Flow instead of putting them all in one sub-coroutine.

edit

---

Use async for concurrency. await gets the future object, merges the concurrent result and sends it to LiveData.

```kotlin
fun getAllItems() {
    
    viewModelScope.launch {
    val folds = viewModelScope.async {
        noteRepository.getFoldersWithNotes()
    }
    val notes = viewModelScope.async {
        noteRepository.getAllNotes()
            .map {
                databaseNoteMapper.mapFromEntityList(it)
            }
    }
    allItems.postValue(folds.await() + notes.await())
  }
}
```